# Change from list of integers to weights between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, list, distribution

In python, I have an list, for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The list will always be sorted. I want to assign weights to the values, such that the weights only go between the values 0 and 1. The largest value will have weight 1, i.e. in this example, 5 will have weight 1.

However, 1 will not have weight 0 (0 is special and not included). I want all other weights to be some fractional value of the greatest number. I am not sure what the best way to approach this problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find the maximum first; since your data is sorted, that'll be the last value; then simply divide the rest by that value:

```
from __future__ import division

maxval = a[-1]
weights = [elem / maxval for elem in a]
```

Demo:

```
>>> maxval = a[-1]
>>> [elem / maxval for elem in a]
[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
```

The `from __future__ import division` import ensures we use floating point division, not integer division. The alternative is to use `maxval = float(a[-1])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def makeWeightedList(list_):
    max_ = max(list_)
    newList = list(map(lambda value: value / max_, list_))
    return newList
```

Btw, this works even if the list isn't sorted. If you really can rely on the list always being sorted (in ascending (or non-descending) order), the maximum will always be the last element, so the second line could instead be:

```
max_ = list_[-1]
```

which would have better performance.

Comment: The input is *sorted*, so using `max()` is overkill; it has to loop over all values in `list_`, while the maximum is the last element, by definition.

Comment: Indeed, I realize that now. It's somewhat strange to expect your list to always be sorted though.

Comment: Why is that strange? Using the `bisect` module you can keep a list sorted when inserting in O(log N) time. That makes keeping a list in sorted order *easy*.

Comment: Quick stylistic question since I'm a python newbie... what's the point of adding the underscore to the end?

Comment: @user1880208: avoiding shadowing the built-in `list` type and `max()` function.